# Format number with dot instead of comma as thousand separator

Tags: php

If I use [`number_format`](http://php.net/number_format) to format a number like this:

```
$price = 1500;
echo number_format($price);
```

Then I get output like this: `1,500`

How can I make the thousands separator be a dot instead of a comma (i.e. get `1.500` as my output instead)?

Answer (score 3):

The third and fourth arguments of [`number_format`](http://php.net/number_format) control the characters used for the decimal point and the thousands separator, respectively. So you can just do this:

```
number_format(
    1500,
    0, // number of decimal places
    ',', // character to use as decimal point
    '.' // character to use as thousands separator
)
```

and get `"1.500"` as your result.